# error: a bin target must be available for `cargo run`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am quite new using Rust language. I try to execute this cargo project/lib from github repository.

https://github.com/smallnest/benchpi

However, after cloning and run `cargo run`, I got this error `error: a bin target must be available for 'cargo run'`

How to properly run this cargo library? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cargo run` [will look for a file](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html) called `src/main.rs` or `src/bin/*.rs` or some other file that's defined to be an application/binary in `Cargo.toml`.  However, this project does not have one of these files.  It is only a library with `src/lib.rs`.  Without writing more code that calls the functions provided by this library, you can only run its unit tests and benchmarking suite.

You can run its unit tests on the latest Rust stable release by running `cargo test`.  However, to run the benchmarks, you'll need to have the Rust nightly release installed.  If you're using rustup to manage your Rust installation, you can install the nightly version of rust and use it to run the benchmarks like:

```sh
$ rustup install nightly
$ cargo +nightly bench
```